# How to locate spam php scripts

Tags: email, php, spam-prevention, exim, email-bounces

Most of the shared servers might be facing the issue of fake PHP code being injected in their sites which may lead to generation of spam mails, redirection to a different site, creation of social engineering URLs etc.

Suggest an effective way to

> find out the spam generating scripts which are not located while doing scanning(maldet etc).
>
> stop email spamming

Comment: I just use version control on the websites I manage.  This way doing an update  on the source files is easy.  I can also nuke out any files I didn't create myself.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the home directory(s) which is creating the high mail queue

> ```
> grep 'cwd=/home' /var/log/exim_mainlog | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d / -f 3 | sort -bg | uniq -c | sort -bg
> ```

Locate if any  multiple POST operation of any PHP file is occurring in the site under that particular home directory. If yes, check the file and lock it down if you find it suspicious. Also block the IP, if it is from a particular one.

> ```
> grep POST /usr/local/apache/domlogs/<homedirectory>/* | grep PHP | grep 200
> ```

I found the  “Pattern 1” in most of the infected files.

**Pattern 1**

> ```
>   grep -irl "GLOBALS.*eval" . | xargs ls -la | grep php
> ```

**Pattern 2**

> ```
> grep -irl "Array.*eval" . | xargs ls -la | grep php
> ```

Pattern 2 is common in PHP files and compressed jquery files. But this pattern is also found in some infected files. So, you should open each file and check whether malicious code is present or not.

**Pattern 3** *(Fake jQuery injections)*

> ```
>    grep -irl "jQuery.min.php" . | xargs ls -la
> ```

Detailed information about jQuery.min.php Malware :https://blog.sucuri.net/2015/11/jquery-min-php-malware-affects-thousands-of-websites.html